# deleteRecord in findAll() vs findQuery()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I just had the following problem: When calling `deleteRecord()` on a model in an ArrayController, whose `content` was set in the route with `findQuery(<model name>, {})`, the model was not removed from the `ArrayController`, even though `deleteRecord` was successful (and I called `save` to persist the action). However, when I switched it to `findAll()`, everything worked as expected. Any ideas why that might be?

I am using Ember 1.4.0-beta.1+canary.4ffecd62 and Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.4+canary.7af6fcb0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find('type', {})`/`findQuery('type', {})` creates a RecordArray.  `findAll('type')`/`find('type')` actually returns a live RecordArray which has all of the current records in the store.

To more fully understand this there are two other methods on the store `all`/`filter` which return Live RecordArrays, but they make no call to the server for records.  You can think of `findAll('type')`/`find('type')` as a method of calling the server then calling the `all` method.

If you wanted you could create a filter based off the results of your `findQuery` to cheat and get a similar effect.

```
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('color', {dummy:'data'});
  },
  setupController:function(controller, model){
    var filter = this.store.filter('color', function(color){
      return model.contains(color);
    }); 

    this._super(controller, filter);
  },
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/114/edit

Comment: When you say 'live RecordArray', you mean that the results get synced with the store? Do you know what the reason is for findQuery and findAll being implemented differently as described above?

Comment: live meaning it recalculates whether or not the record belongs any time a record enter's or exits the store or the record's state changes.  It isn't necessarily a cheap thing to keep track of every array/collection created and remove items on delete etc.  My guess is they just reused the all filter in the findall functionality for code reuse sake, which ended up giving it more functionality than the other collections.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know how this works, though it's not particularly consistent and is likely cause quite some confusion..

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the effect you want without creating another filter, you can also call something like this in the controller:

```
record.deleteRecord;
record.save(); // or record.destroyRecord() to combine the two calls
this.get('model').removeObject(record);
```

This will remove the deleted record from either type of array object.